# whats the seed for spacefiller pattern in conway's game of life

Tags: conways-game-of-life

Can anybody tell me what is the seed for spacefiller pattern in Conway's game of life ? I am planning to include some interesting patterns for user in my game.

Thanks much,

Comment: This sounds like a slightly more appropriate question for gamedev.stackexchange.com. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Golly](http://sourceforge.net/projects/golly/), a really nice Sourceforge Game-of-Life project with a huge number of seeds:

```
                    ███   ███
                   █  █   █  █
████                  █   █                  ████
█   █                 █   █                 █   █
█        █            █   █            █        █
 █  █  ██  █                         █  ██  █  █
      █     █       ███   ███       █     █
      █     █        █     █        █     █
      █     █        ███████        █     █
 █  █  ██  █  ██    █       █    ██  █  ██  █  █
█        █   ██    ███████████    ██   █        █
█   █         ██                 ██         █   █
████           ███████████████████           ████
                █ █           █ █
                   ███████████
                   █         █
                    █████████
                        █
                    ███   ███
                      █   █

                     ███ ███
                     ███ ███
                    █ ██ ██ █
                    ███   ███
                     █     █
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are referring to the [glider pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glider_%28Conway%27s_Life%29)?

One of the frames looks like;

```
010
001
111
```

[image]

Edit:
Try
http://www.argentum.freeserve.co.uk/lex_s.htm#spacefiller

Comment: I am not asking for glider. Space filler is a much bigger beautiful pattern that eventually fills out the space and looks like a bug at starting. Check it out, its cool. I need the seed for it. Nice tattoo though !!

Comment: Presumably newcoder vaguely remembers the shape but not the specifics

Comment: Thats true Richard. I am searching for the specifics and will share with everyone if i get them before I get some answer here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe missKK is looking for a *Conway's Game of Life* pattern that will, if placed in empty space, fill the space with an agar.  Although new *Life* patterns are discovered all the time, as of today the smallest known pattern is Tim Coe's "[Max](http://www.radicaleye.com/lifepage/patterns/max.html)", a 187-cell pattern which fits in a 27x27 bounding box:

```
#N Max
#O Tim Coe
#C A spacefiller that fills space with zebra stripes.
#C www.conwaylife.com/wiki/index.php?title=Max
x = 27, y = 27, rule = s23/b3
18bo8b$17b3o7b$12b3o4b2o6b$11bo2b3o2bob2o4b$10bo3bobo2bobo5b$10bo4bobo
bobob2o2b$12bo4bobo3b2o2b$4o5bobo4bo3bob3o2b$o3b2obob3ob2o9b2ob$o5b2o
5bo13b$bo2b2obo2bo2bob2o10b$7bobobobobobo5b4o$bo2b2obo2bo2bo2b2obob2o
3bo$o5b2o3bobobo3b2o5bo$o3b2obob2o2bo2bo2bob2o2bob$4o5bobobobobobo7b$
10b2obo2bo2bob2o2bob$13bo5b2o5bo$b2o9b2ob3obob2o3bo$2b3obo3bo4bobo5b4o
$2b2o3bobo4bo12b$2b2obobobobo4bo10b$5bobo2bobo3bo10b$4b2obo2b3o2bo11b$
6b2o4b3o12b$7b3o17b$8bo!
```

The [Lifewiki](http://www.conwaylife.com/wiki/Category:Spacefillers) website has more information on this pattern and other known spacefillers.